# Prove the properties of Fibonacci sequence $F_p$ $F_{p-1}$ $F_{p+1}$ mod p for prime p

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, quadratic-residues

p is a prime and Let $F_{n}$ denotes the Fibonacci sequence.

I want to show the following properties of $F_p$:

$F_p\equiv\left (\frac{p}{5}  \right ) (mod ~p)\tag{0}$

And for $F_{p+1}$:

$F_{p+1}\equiv1 ~(mod ~p)~~if~~p \equiv \pm ~1 (mod~5)\tag{1}$

$F_{p+1}\equiv0 ~(mod ~p)~~if~~p \equiv \pm ~2 (mod~5)\tag{2}$

For $F_{p-1}$:

$F_{p-1}\equiv0 ~(mod ~p)~~if~~p \equiv \pm ~1 (mod~5)\tag{3}$

$F_{p-1}\equiv1 ~(mod ~p)~~if~~p \equiv \pm ~2 (mod~5)\tag{4}$

So $F_{p-1}$ and $F_{p+1}$ look like "converse"

I have tried to start with $F_{0} = 0$ , $F_{1} = 1$, $F_{2} = 1$ and use the property of Fibonacci sequence such that: $F_{n} = F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ but I failed.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: `\pmod{p}` will produce the space, parentheses, and roman typefaced "mod".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the Binet Formula:

$$ F_n= \frac{
\Big(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\Big)^n
-
\Big(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\Big)^n}
{\sqrt{ 5}},$$ from which, after expansion of the binomials, you have
$$ F_n= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k\ge0} {n \choose 2k+1}5^k,$$
and then you easily obtain the desired results by letting $n =p, p-1 $ and $p+1$ in the above sum and then reducing modulo $p$.

Comment: That's great and I get it